# Sistema de auth Laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como autenticar o login do usuário e senha no laravel, estou tentando já tem um tempo mas não consigo.

Rotas

```
Route::get('/login',['uses' => 'loginController@login','as' => 'login']);    
Route::post('/login',['uses'=>'loginController@checkLogin','as' => 'VerificarLogin']);
```

Meu controller

```
    class loginController extends Controller
    {

    public function login(){

        return view('Inicial.login');
    }
    public function teste(){

        return view('teste');
    }

     public function checkLogin(Request $request ){

        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');

       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            return 1;
        }

        return 0; 
    }
```

Meu arquivo de auth.php

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],  

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'table' => 'usuarios',
        'model' => App\Usuario::class,
    ],
```

Minha classe Usuario

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = ['nome','password','email','data_nascimento','rg','funcao','telefone'];

    protected $table = 'usuarios';    
}`
```

E meu form galera

```
              <form class="form-horizontal new-lg-form" id="loginform" action="{{ route('VerificarLogin') }}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group  m-t-20">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label>Endereço de Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label>Senha</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" name="password">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pull-left p-t-0">
                      <input id="checkbox-signup" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="checkbox-signup"> Lembrar-me </label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="to-recover" class="text-dark pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5"></i> Esqueceu a senha ?</a> </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block btn-rounded text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Entrar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </form>
```

Na minha verificação nunca consigo entrar ou logar.  Se alguém tiver um projeto que seja similar manda o link para eu olhar ou baixar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::post('/login',['uses'=>'loginController@checkLogin','as' => 'VerificarLogin'])->middleware('auth');
```

Faltou você dizer ao Laravel que é para essa rota ser protegida chamando a função middleware como fiz acima.
Esse não é o único modo de proteger uma rota pois fica muito trabalhoso e de difícil manutenção você colocar uma chamada ao mddleware em cada rota uma saida seria usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::post('/login',['uses'=>'loginController@checkLogin','as' => 'VerificarLogin']);
});
```

Tudo que estiver dentro daquele group passará pela verificação de que se o usuário está logado ou não. Caso o usuário não esteja logado será apresentado um erro ou você pode definir uma página para ele mostrar, normalmente é redirecionado para a tela de login.
Você encontra mais informação em https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routeshttps://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: Marcos, ainda sim não consigo ter o meu retorno no checkLogin que está no meu controller, pq quero saber se os dados dele tem no banco e depois redirecionar ele para uma rota... não pegou

Comment: No meu controller ele está sempre retornando 0 mesmo quando coloco os dados corretos que está no banco

Comment: Joan dentro do seu controller onde está: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            return 1;
        } você tem que colocar return view('nome_da_view), e o laravel vai redirecionar vaocê para a view e fazer o login. Faz o seguinte, proteje a rota e tenta acessar sem logar tem que dar um erro. Daí você loga e fecha a página sem fechar o navegador e entra na página daí vc tem que ser redirecionado para a página protegida.

Comment: é isso quando eu colocar login e a senha o meu controller tem que me retorna '1' e não '0'

Comment: Me diz uma coisa quando você cadastrou o senha no banco de dados você aplicou o hash ou gravou direto a senha sem criptografia?

Comment: a senha está sem hash gravei direito a senha tentei varias coisas diferentes mas nunca pega

Comment: O problema deve estar aí faz assim usa a função bcrypt() para encriptar a senha. Fica mais ou manos assim $user->password = bcrypt("sua senha"); O laravel quando vai fazer a checagem da senha encripta a senha que você passa e checa. Depois que você gravar a senha encriptada no seu bando de dados vai funcionar, e você não pode esquecer de que todo novo usuário deve ter usa senha encriptada antes de gravar no banco, pois no banco você grava somente a senha encriptada. Dá um retorno para saber se funcionou.

Comment: ok man vou testa aqui

Comment: esse comando é para eu cadastrar as senha criptografadas ou para verificar se a senha está com hash ?

Comment: Para cadastrar a senha criptografada.

Comment: deu certo man era isso mesmo

Comment: Você é o cara, vlw man

Comment: Que bom que funcionou amigo, obrigado por marcar a resposta. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Joan Marcos,

O Laravel tem a funcionalidade de autenticação pronto, basta através do console executar: php artisan make:auth

Se você estiver com a conexão com o banco configurado no arquivo .ENV ele cria as tabelas e monta a página para login com usuário usando template do Bootstrap.

Dá uma olhada: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication

Como o amigo Marcos mencionou você pode proteger suas páginas através das rotas usando um Middleware https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware que facilita bastante e o código acaba ficando bem menor e mais limpo.

Você também pode inserir um if na sua view para mostrar apenas se o usuário estiver logado usando:

@if(Auth::check())

... SEU CÓDIGO HTML ...

@endif

Espero ter lhe ajudado!

Até mais!

Comment: vlw man ajudou sim ^^